# Scale each instance by index

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm having trouble scaling each instance by index going from small to large for each instance one at the time. Right now my instances just go from large to small for the whole length:

[image]

And here are the nodes that go into the scale of *instance on points* node:

[image]

Hope that someone can help me out :) Thanks.

Edit: The answer below solved my question, but is there a way to make it loop through the instances? Now it just stops when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure what you are going for, but with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you! This was exactly what I was looking for. If you have the time, it would be awesome to have an explanation of what's going on to have it go through the index like that :)

Now I just need to figure out how to loop the scale through the index, instead of stopping when it reaches the end.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!