# Loop through instances (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

Reference to this question: [Scale each instance by index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254952/scale-each-instance-by-index)

I kinda made it work with the answer provided in the previous post, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to loop the instances when it reaches the end of the sequence.

What am I missing here:

[image]

Here's a reference of the effect I'm trying to achieve: https://www.instagram.com/p/CM5DvnqH92e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do a looping animation in geometry nodes:

[image]

I use the frame, compare this to the index, and scale only that instance on this frame.
On the next frame, the next "index"/instance will be scaled. And so on.
To get the looping effect i need indizes from 0..10. So i use module with number of instances to get his effect.

result:

[image]

If you want to change the speed of the animation, just plug in a map node in between like this:

[image]

by changing the "to max" values you can change the animation speed.